# Animate Mesh in a wavelike movement

Tags: animation

I want to built a tower out of these cylinders and animate the X-Y Scale of the individual cylinders over time in a wavelike pattern.

Is there a quick way to to that ?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You could use a sin() function and a driver to animate e.g. the X scale. In `Object Properties` under `Transform` for one of the cylinders, click the number in `Scale: X` and type in something like:

```
#1.0 + 0.2 * sin(frame * 2.0 * pi / 30.0)
```

That'll vary scale every 30 frames between 0.8 and 1.2. For later cylinders you can offset the phase a little:

```
#1.0 + 0.2 * sin((frame + 5) * 2.0 * pi / 30.0)
```

That'll put that cylinder 5 frames ahead in the animation.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [wave modifer](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/dev/modeling/modifiers/deform/wave.html). It should result in about what you're looking for, and it can be adjusted to fit your model.

Comment: Some questions only require a one-line answer (e.g. Where is a certain setting in a menu?).  This question imo requires a little more effort.  This might be better placed in the comments section or else elaborate more on how the OP can use the wave modifier to accomplish this.